# Is it possible to display several objects using a detail view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm very new to Django, and posting here so please excuse my ignorance and code formatting (got messed up when I pasted).

I created a very basic list and detail view where I have two models, I pass the ID from an object in model1 into the detail view and return all model2 objects, where "execid" matchs model1s ID. However, there will be several objects in model2 that match the ID passed from model1.

I get the error "get() returned more than one Exec -- it returned 2!"

Which I've understood to mean that a detail view cannot pass more than one object in.

My views:

```
class tradeListView(ListView):
 def get_queryset(self):
    return Trade.objects.filter(username=self.request.user)
 template_name = 'dashboard/trade_list.html'
 context_object_name = "trade"

class execDetailView(DetailView):
 template_name = "dashboard/exec_list.html"

 def get_queryset(self):
    return Exec.objects.filter(username=self.request.user)

 def get_object(self):
    id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
    return get_object_or_404(Exec, execid=id_)
```

my models:

```
class Trade(models.Model):
exittime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, db_column='exittime')
entrytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, db_column='entrytime')
duration = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='duration')
ticker = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='ticker')
direction = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='direction')
quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='quantity', default=None)
entry = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, db_column='entry')
exit = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, db_column='exit')
cost = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, db_column='cost', default=0)
percent = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=100, db_column='percent', default=0)
profit = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, db_column='profit')
username = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='username')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('execdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Exec(models.Model):
exectime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, db_column='exectime')
ticker = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='ticker')
direction = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='direction')
quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='quantity', default=None)
price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, db_column='price')
cost = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, db_column='cost', default=0)
username = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='username')
execid = models.IntegerField(db_column='execid', default=None)
```

execid is that value that needs to match the trade models ID. all exec objects are created with a valid id from a trade object*

Is there is possible to do what I am doing, even if it is in an entirely different manner? Thank you!

Comment: It seems there are multiple objects with same `execid`, hence you should use ListView, instead of detail view. Also use `ForeignKey` field instead of `IntegerField` for `execid` in the models.

Comment: Thank you @ruddra. changing it to a list view worked, I moved my id_ declaration into get_queryset and filtered in the return. Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes